# Redefinition of z_stream_s, gz_header_s, gzfile_s in zlib.h for objective c after upgrade to xcode13

Tags: objective-c, zlib

After upgrade to xcode13.4, redefinition of struct  z_stream_s, gz_header_s, gzfile_s in zlib.h.

I added to guard to avoid the redefinition in the starting and ending

```
#ifndef ZLIB_H
#define ZLIB_H

------ coding

#endif
```

Code where the error occurring

```
typedef struct z_stream_s {
    z_const Bytef *next_in;     /* next input byte */
    uInt     avail_in;  /* number of bytes available at next_in */
    uLong    total_in;  /* total number of input bytes read so far */

    Bytef    *next_out; /* next output byte will go here */
    uInt     avail_out; /* remaining free space at next_out */
    uLong    total_out; /* total number of bytes output so far */

    z_const char *msg;  /* last error message, NULL if no error */
    struct internal_state FAR *state; /* not visible by applications */

    alloc_func zalloc;  /* used to allocate the internal state */
    free_func  zfree;   /* used to free the internal state */
    voidpf     opaque;  /* private data object passed to zalloc and zfree */

    int     data_type;  /* best guess about the data type: binary or text
                           for deflate, or the decoding state for inflate */
    uLong   adler;      /* Adler-32 or CRC-32 value of the uncompressed data */
    uLong   reserved;   /* reserved for future use */
} z_stream;

typedef struct z_stream_s FAR *z_streamp;

typedef struct gz_header_s {
    int     text;       /* true if compressed data believed to be text */
    uLong   time;       /* modification time */
    int     xflags;     /* extra flags (not used when writing a gzip file) */
    int     os;         /* operating system */
    Bytef   *extra;     /* pointer to extra field or Z_NULL if none */
    uInt    extra_len;  /* extra field length (valid if extra != Z_NULL) */
    uInt    extra_max;  /* space at extra (only when reading header) */
    Bytef   *name;      /* pointer to zero-terminated file name or Z_NULL */
    uInt    name_max;   /* space at name (only when reading header) */
    Bytef   *comment;   /* pointer to zero-terminated comment or Z_NULL */
    uInt    comm_max;   /* space at comment (only when reading header) */
    int     hcrc;       /* true if there was or will be a header crc */
    int     done;       /* true when done reading gzip header (not used
                           when writing a gzip file) */
} gz_header;

struct gzFile_s {
    unsigned have;
    unsigned char *next;
    z_off64_t pos;
};
```

[image]

I replaced the latest zlib.h also but the same redefinition error occurring again.

These files are used to generate the qrcode

redefintion issue occurring in all these files

[image]

[image]

When i click the error occur it goes to the line where struct z_stream_s is defined

```
typedef struct z_stream_s {
```

In that error shows that it has been already defined in the file unzip.c

in the unzip.c when i look into that zlib.h has been include in the both unzip.h and unzip.c

in unzip.h

```
#ifndef _unz_H
#define _unz_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef _ZLIB_H
#include "zlib.h"
#endif

#ifndef _ZLIBIOAPI_H
#include "ioapi.h"
#endif
```

in unzip.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "zlib.h"
#include "unzip.h"

#ifdef STDC
#  include <stddef.h>
#  include <string.h>
#  include <stdlib.h>
#endif
#ifdef NO_ERRNO_H
    extern int errno;
#else
#   include <errno.h>
#endif
```

These files are used to generate the QRCODE

and the redefinition error continues on file by file zip.c, zip.h, pngpriv.h, pngstruct.h like that it goes on

Note:The same project is working fine in Xcode 12.4, but in latest Xcode 13 Its shows the redefinition error

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `#ifndef` etc. is already there in zlib.h. You would need to provide more information on what, exactly, you are doing, and what, exactly, the error message is.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i added the image of error, please look over that and provide me the solution to this problem

Comment: Still can't tell anything about what's gong on, and please don't post images. Copy and paste. Where is the zlib.h that you are including coming from? What is the source code that is including it? Is unzip.c your code? Put _your_ code in the question.

Comment: This is used to generator qrcode i added the screenshot of files we are using, please check @MarkAdler

Comment: What did I say about not posting images?

Comment: my apology for posting the image, now i updated the question please check it @MarkAdler

Comment: @MarkAdler When i click the error occur it goes to the line where struct z_stream_s is defined.  In that error shows that it has been already defined in the file unzip.c. In the unzip.c when i look into that zlib.h has been include in the both unzip.h and unzip.c. These files are used to generate the QRCODE. The redefinition error continues on file by file zip.c, zip.h, pngpriv.h, pngstruct.h.... like that it goes on. Note:The same project is working fine in Xcode 12.4, but in latest Xcode 13 Its shows the redefinition error, unzip.h and unzip.c code is added in the question above, please